# Can't find main with Eclipse Default Drools Example DroolsTest

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, drools

Getting "Error: Could not find or load main class com.sample.DroolsTest"  Something isn't configured correctly in my dev env.  I could use some help, I figure this should just work.  I must be doing something wrong or skipping a step.

Steps:
Eclipse File -> New Project -> Drools Project
From wizard select, "Add a sample HelloWorld rule file to this project" and "Add a sample Java class for loading and executing the HelloWorld rules"

Right click on POM
Run-As - >Maven Build

Then, when I right click on DroolsTest Run-as Java Application, I get the above error.

Here is my POM and details about my environment.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.simple.drools</groupId>
<artifactId>drools-hello-world</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Mac : Version 10.10.4

JDK : java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

IDE : Eclipse MARS; including Maven Plugins

.bash_profile :

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export M2_HOME=/Users/me/Development/apache-maven-3.3.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Relevant Installed Software :

```
Drools 6.2.0.Final
GEF 3.10.0.201506010206
```

Answer (score 0):

I never did get to the bottom of it.  What I did instead was install JBoss Developer Studio with the supporting plugins for Drools development.  The same default Drools Project worked out of the box.  Switching the IDE was simpler.